# Upload Download File Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, file-upload, download

I have created a website using Visual Studio C#, with different functionalities for students and teachers. The only thing remaining is that I wish to create two more pages, one in the teacher folder, and other on the student folder (access is dependant on roles).

The page on the teacher side uploads a file (in any format) to a database. This I believe will be stored in a table in the form of varbinary. And the page on student side provides  a link to download the desired file. I have been through a lot of different web pages now, but can't seem to achieve any solution to it. Please can someone tell me how to do it??

I believe that uploading is easier. All I need to do is implement a FileUpload control and using a query I can store that the data in a table.

But what about downloading? I saw an example which used HttpHandlers, but that was for displaying images in the browser. I want to upload files in other format and then download the same on the computer (that is the student would be able to download it)

Comment: I think you need something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/308552/Upload-and-Download-Files-to-SQL-Servers-in-ASP-Ne). The article shows a table structure to store any kind of binary file. The Default.aspx page shows how to both upload a file and later download it. To send the file to the browser (the download), just use the Response object (see GetFile.aspx from the article): // Send the file to the browser Response.AddHeader("Content-type", contentType); Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name); Response.BinaryWrite(data); Response.Flush(); Re

Comment: Inserting binary file data in to a database is generally a bad idea. Can't you upload the files to a directory, and store a reference to its URL/file path in the database instead?

Comment: @Alfie: Yes I could try to do that. But I dont know how to. I am relatively new to ASP.Net and all I know is the database one. Any help even with uploading to a folder and downloading from there would be welcome. The reason I want to use the databae is that the user can then reference the notes according to the document ID which would be automatically generated and stored in the table information

Comment: @daspn : your example looks really helpful. I will try that

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/308552/Upload-and-Download-Files-to-SQL-Servers-in-ASP-Ne).

The article shows a table structure (SQL Server) to store any kind of binary file:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ContentType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Size] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Files] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    [ID] ASC
    )WITH (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In your upload page, put the following controls:

```
<input type="file" name="fileInput" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload File" runat="server" onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
```

Go to the code-behind file of you upload page and add the following code to handle the button's click event and save the file to the database:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;
    foreach (string fileTagName in files)
    {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[fileTagName];
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                    int size = file.ContentLength;
                    string name = file.FileName;
                    int position = name.LastIndexOf("\\");
                    name = name.Substring(position + 1);
                    string contentType = file.ContentType;
                    byte[] fileData = new byte[size];
                    file.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, size);

                    FileUtilities.SaveFile(name, contentType, size, fileData);
            }
    }
    DataTable fileList = FileUtilities.GetFileList();
    gvFiles.DataSource = fileList;
    gvFiles.DataBind();
}
```

The `FileUtilities` class must have methods to save the file and later retrieve it from the database:

```
public static void SaveFile(string name, string contentType, int size, byte[] data)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
    {
        OpenConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        string commandText = "INSERT INTO Files VALUES(@Name, @ContentType, ";
        commandText = commandText + "@Size, @Data)";
        cmd.CommandText = commandText;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@size", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.VarBinary);

        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = name;
        cmd.Parameters["@ContentType"].Value = contentType;
        cmd.Parameters["@size"].Value = size;
        cmd.Parameters["@Data"].Value = data;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
}

public static DataTable GetFileList()
{
        DataTable fileList = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            OpenConnection(connection);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name, ContentType, Size FROM Files";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(fileList);

            connection.Close();
        }

        return fileList;
}

public static DataTable GetAFile(int id)
{
        DataTable file = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            OpenConnection(connection);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name, ContentType, Size, Data FROM Files "
                + "WHERE ID=@ID";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = id;

            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(file);

            connection.Close();
        }

        return file;
}
```

To list the available files add a `GridView` to you download page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFiles" CssClass="GridViewStyle"
            AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server">
            <FooterStyle CssClass="GridViewFooterStyle" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" />    
            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="GridViewSelectedRowStyle" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="GridViewPagerStyle" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
            <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server"
                                            NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "GetFile.aspx?ID={0}") %>'
                                            Text="Download"></asp:HyperLink>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and load it by adding the following code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (! IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable fileList = FileUtilities.GetFileList();
            gvFiles.DataSource = fileList;
            gvFiles.DataBind();
        }
}
```

Finally, in the `GetFile` page add the following to the code-behind in order to implement the download feature:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

        DataTable file = FileUtilities.GetAFile(id);
        DataRow row = file.Rows[0];

        string name = (string)row["Name"];
        string contentType = (string)row["ContentType"];
        Byte[] data = (Byte[])row["Data"];

        // Send the file to the browser
        Response.AddHeader("Content-type", contentType);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
        Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```